# Is there a function similar to "andmap" in clojure?

Tags: clojure

I want to apply a series of tests on my list and make sure that all the tests are passed.
Is there a function similar to "andmap" in Clojure?

Comment: could you add an emaple input and output?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use `every?`:

```
user=> (every? string? '("hi" 1))
false
```

Here's the documentation on [`every?`](http://www.clojure.org/api#toc244).

Answer (score 2):

Clojure 1.3 will add every-pred (and the related some-fn for the "or" version).

clojure.core/every-pred
([p] [p1 p2] [p1 p2 p3] [p1 p2 p3 & ps])

Takes a set of predicates and returns a function f that returns true if all of its
  composing predicates return a logical true value against all of its arguments, else it     returns
  false. Note that f is short-circuiting in that it will stop execution on the first
  argument that triggers a logical false result against the original predicates.

A naive implementation might be:

(defn every-pred [& preds] (fn [& args] (every? #(every? % args) preds)))

but the actual implementation will have better performance.

Answer (score 1):

`every?` will ask "Does this one function return true for each member of the seq", which is close to what I think you are asking for. An improvement on `every?` would take a list of functions and ask "Are all these predicates true for every member of this seq".

Here is a first attempt:

```
(defn andmap? [data tests]
  (every? true? (for [d data, f tests]
                  (f d))))

user> (andmap? '(2 4 8) [even? pos?])
true
user> (andmap? '(2 4 8) [even? odd?])
false
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote `andmap` as a macro which takes predicates as its arguments and builds a function that "wraps an `and` around the predicates", i.e.,

```
(andmap integer? odd?) 
==>
(fn [x] (and (integer? x)
             (odd? x)))
```

(it doesn't expand to *exactly* this, but it expands to something equivalent to this)

This has the advantage that it shortcuircuts on the predicates so you can write

```
(every? (andmap integer? odd?) [1 3 "a string"])
```

without getting a runtime exception as you would get with [Arthurs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209824/is-there-a-function-similar-to-andmap-in-clojure/1209990#1209990).

Here is the definition of `andmap`:

```
(defmacro andmap 
  ([]       `(fn [& x#] true))
  ([p & ps] `(fn [& x#] (and (apply ~p x#)
                             (apply (andmap ~@ps) x#)))))
```

It is also possible to define `andmap` as an function which also short-circuits on it's predicates due to lazyness:

```
(defn andmap [& ps]
  (fn [& x]
    (every? true? (map (fn [p] (apply p x)) ps))))
```

The predicates to andmap can take an arbitrary number of arguments, so it is possible to write

```
(map (andmap #(and (integer? %1)
                   (integer? %2))
             #(and (odd? %1)
                   (even? %2))
             <)
     [1 3 9]
     [2 6 "string"])
```

which evaluates to `(true true false)`.